# "Error character" when not finding searched value in list of tuples

Tags: haskell

In my Haskell homework, my task is to create a recursive function that accepts a Char and a list of tuple pairs.
I want to scan the first elements of the tuples, and if it matches with the input 'char', then return the second element of the tuple.
If there is no matching then it should return `'#'`

Here is my code so far:

```
find_pair :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] ->  b
find_pair _ [] = error "#"
find_pair x ((a,b):xs) = if x == a then b else find_pair x xs
```

It should work like this:

```
find_pair 'b' [('b', 'g'), ('c', 'h'), ('a', 'f')] = 'g'
find_pair '!' [('b', 'g'), ('c', 'h'), ('a', 'f')] = '#'
```

It works almost fine, but my teacher dose not accept it since at the '#' part my function returns:

```
*** Exception: #
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at haskell.hs:19:19 in main:Main
```

and not `'#'`
But if i write my function like this:

```
find_pair :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] ->  b
find_pair _ [] =  '#' 
find_pair x ((a,b):xs)  = if x == a then  b else find_pair x xs
```

It dose not even compile and gives me this error:

```
haskell.hs:19:19: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `b' with actual type `Char'
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          find_pair :: forall a b. Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> b
        at haskell.hs:18:1-41
    * In the expression: '#'
      In an equation for `find_pair': find_pair _ [] = '#'
    * Relevant bindings include
        find_pair :: a -> [(a, b)] -> b (bound at haskell.hs:19:1)
   |
19 | find_pair _ [] =  '#'
   |                   ^^^
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to return a character, but your type signature specifies a generic return type `b`, which is not necessarily a character. A generic type means "whatever type you give me, I can work with that" - the main point being that *you don't choose that type, but whoever calls your function does*.

So if you really want to return a special character, your type signature has to say so:

```
find_pair :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a, Char)] ->  Char
find_pair _ [] = '#'
find_pair x ((a,b):xs) = if x == a then b else find_pair x xs
```

However, returning special values to indicate special outcomes is fragile. What if your input actually happens to contain the character `'#'`? How would the consumer be able to tell whether you found the character `'#'` or didn't find anything?

When a function may or may not have a result, the standard way to do that in Haskell is to return a value wrapped in `Maybe`:

```
find_pair :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] ->  Maybe b
find_pair _ [] = Nothing
find_pair x ((a,b):xs) = if x == a then Just b else find_pair x xs
```

Here, the function will return `Just b` when it finds an element, or `Nothing` when it doesn't.